# Background fixed up go a bit up when scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a new website, and I am using:

```
background-attachment:  fixed;
background-color: #645862;
background-image:url("images/bg/bg.jpg");
background-position:  center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: white;
cursor: default;
padding: 6em 0;
text-align: center;
height: auto;
position: relative;
```

So that when I scroll the background img does not follow up as with the:

```
background-attachment:  scroll;
```

But how can I get that effect that some pages use where the background img follow up, but only slow? like on the new Twitter top header img ? Here is an example https://twitter.com/verge

Comment: One word: parallax :)

Comment: http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/jquery-parallax-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Grumann!

I found this JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
        parallaxScroll();
    });

    function parallaxScroll(){
        var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.fullintro').css('background-position','center -'+((scrolledY*0.4))+'px');
    }
});
```

Where "fullintro" is the class of my div with the background img.